# Upload File to a ftp server in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ftp

I am making a data analysis web application which allow user to upload some files to a FTP server and get results after some calculation.

The problem I have now is how to make the interface for user to upload their files.
Basically, **how to set up a connection between browser and ftp server.**

So is it possible to do it in a browser without having a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be possible to call FTP from HTTP. If there is WebDav (FTP over HTTP) server enabled on backend than this could work.